# LifeCycleContext vs FacesContext

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I know all information pertinent to a request is stored in the `FacesContext` class and it is trashed at the end of request. So how is the `LifeCycleContext` class different from the `FacesContext` class? How long does it live? Is it GC'ed at the end of an Http request?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Java doc and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31974/adf_lifecycle.htm.
I seems the LifeCycleContext is responsible for grouping the contexts ADF puts in place. FacesContext on the other hand is a Faces construct for holding faces request specifics. The LifeCycleContext adds to what the FacesContext provides. Remember ADF is build upon (and add to) Trinidad, and Trinidad is build upon (and adds to) Faces.

It should be released the end of the request. When it is garbage collected is up to the JVM.